# Migrating bridged eth0 with static IP from /etc/network/interfaces to networkd

Tags: networking, network-bridge, systemd-networkd

Under Ubuntu 16.04, my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 144.76.AAA.BBB
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 144.76.CCC.DDD
  bridge_ports eth0
```

How would this translate to a `networkd` configuration in Ubuntu 18.04? This is what I tried, unsuccessfully (after rebooting, I can't reach the machine any more):

**`/etc/systemd/network/01-br0.netdev`:**

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

**`/etc/systemd/network/01-br0.network`:**

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=144.76.AAA.BBB/29
Gateway=144.76.CCC.DDD
```

**`/etc/systemd/network/10-enp4s0.network`:**

```
[Match]
Name=enp4s0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

This is the output in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: br0: netdev ready
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: Enumeration completed
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: enp4s0: Link is not managed by us
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: br0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd-networkd[616]: enp4s0: IPv6 successfully disabled
Jun  2 13:30:51 master systemd[1]: Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Jun  2 13:30:52 master networkd-dispatcher[749]: No valid path found for iwconfig
Jun  2 13:30:52 master systemd[1]: Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd[616]: enp4s0: Gained carrier
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd[616]: enp4s0: Configured
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd[616]: br0: Gained carrier
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd[616]: br0: Gained IPv6LL
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd[616]: br0: Configured
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd-wait-online[661]: managing: br0
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd-wait-online[661]: managing: enp4s0
Jun  2 13:30:53 master systemd-networkd-wait-online[661]: ignoring: lo
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is copied and pasted from a yet to be published update to the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html):

Configure the bridge by editing your netplan configuration found in /etc/netplan/:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
```

Enter the appropriate values for your physical interface and network.
Now apply the configuration to enable the bridge:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

The new bridge interface should now be up and running. The brctl provides useful information about the state of the bridge, controls which interfaces are part of the bridge, etc. See man brctl for more information.

There is a static example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995360/configuration-of-a-bridge-with-a-static-ip-with-the-netplan-to-be-used-with-linu?rq=1).